# Architecture design patterns used by AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns, data-structures

What are the architectural design patterns that the AngularJS Codebase follows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularJS follows a variant of the Model View Controller(MVC) design pattern. AngularJS handles the passing of models to views from a controller based on a respective route.

Views are updated whenever a model changes and models are updated whenever a view changes by data-binding elements on a view to a specific model. Controllers are used to manipulate DOM elements through functions.

By design, AngularJS forces you to write MVC styled code. If you use AngularJS, you are using MVC. I say that it follows a variant because traditional MVC architecture for web development was previously server-side in languages like PHP, ASP.NET MVC, Ruby on Rails, etc. for controllers and client-side for views.

Now with robust client side libraries such as AngularJS or KnockoutJS, we can provide more responsive and efficient applications as single page applications. Web 1.0 dealt primarily with multiple page applications whereas Web 2.0 and beyond is moving towards service oriented architecture.

You can't get away from having any server-side code, but you can write your entire web app in the browser and not rely on the server sending new HTML for each view.

Comment: Hello, Cameron. Would you mind to expand "variant of MVC" you mentioned that Angular using? Advantage / Disadvantage for using any of those with Anuglar will be really really helpful as well! thank you!